# How to find the corresponding subtriangle of a position inside a rectangle

Tags: java, math, position

I have a dynamic rectangle in which 4 subtriangles (t0-t3) are created (by adding the diagonals from the vertices). When given a certain x|y coordinate what is the fastest way to find the corresponding triangle?. The rectangle has a specific position and dimension. I only need the right "id" so not the vertices of the triangle, so for example in the graphic when p1 is given as position 0 should be returned, 3 at p2 and 2 at p3, ...

One possible solution of course would be to create the triangles and query if the point is contained in one of them, but it feels like a very complicated solution for something that simple.
I also thought about creating a vector from the center and measuring the angle but it also seems complicated in a rectangle with varying dimensions.

[Example Rectangle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mg76E.jpg)

Comment: In words: compare the slope of the line segment from the lower left corner of the rectangle to your query point with the slope of the diagonal connecting the lower left corner of the rectangle to the upper right corner. This tells you whether the point belong to t0 or t3 versus t1 or t2. Similarly, compare the slope of the line segment from the lower right corner to the query point with the slope of the diagonal connecting the lower right corner to the upper left corner. You then know if the point is in t0 or t1 versus t2 or t3. Together this tells which of the four triangles the point is in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following:

Let the bottom left corner of the rectangle be (0,0) and the top right corner be (1,1).  Now, the two lines that form the triangles are defined as:

```
y = x and y = 1-x
```

For every point except (.5,.5) we have a ternary conditional for a given x or y.  For example, given that x = .2, we know that:

if y < .2, we're in the bottom triangle (t2),
elif  .2 < y < .8, we're in the left triangle (t3),
else, we're in the top triangle (t0).

Hopefully this helps without explicitly giving you the code.

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: No problem!  Glad it was helpful.  Figure out the equations of the two lines, and you'll be good to go.